# Storing game data in a database for many levels

Tags: python, sqlite, pygame

I am creating a platform game and there will be about 50 levels. I have a database with a user table that has username and password and I want to link it to a game data table. I want to store the time taken for each level and whether or not it has been completed in the table. What is the best way to do this as I have considered a separate record for each level for each player, but this seems very long.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to databases, you will need to do a little exploration into how to deal with queries using multiple tables. What you probably want is a User table, a Level table and a UserLevels table, where the UserLevels table will have entries for the User.id, Levele.id, and time taken or whatever other information you need. I hope that makes sense.